# $\underset{i\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}p_i=p$; $f$ is continuous if and only if $\underset{i\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f(p_i)=f(p)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$. Take a sequence $\{p_i\}_{i\ge1}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\underset{i\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}p_i=p$. Then. $f$ is continuous if and only if $\underset{i\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f(p_i)=f(p)$.

**Proof.**

Only if part:
$f$ is continuous $\Rightarrow f$ is continious at $p$ $\Rightarrow\forall\varepsilon>0~\exists\delta_{\varepsilon,p}>0$ such that $\forall y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, if $\|y-p\|<\delta_{\varepsilon,p}$ then $\|f(y)-f(p)\|<\varepsilon$.

Also, $\underset{i\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}p_i=p\Rightarrow\forall\varepsilon>0~\exists N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N_\varepsilon$, $\|p_i-p\|<\varepsilon$.

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrarily. Then, for $\delta_{\varepsilon,p}~\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$, $\|p_i-p\|<\delta_{\varepsilon,p}$$\Rightarrow$$\|f(p_i)-f(p)\|<\varepsilon$.

$\because\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrarily fixed,

$\therefore\forall\varepsilon>0~\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\ge N$, $\|f(p_i)-f(p)\|<\varepsilon\Rightarrow\underset{i\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}f(p_i)=f(p)$.

> The "only if part" only seems to require the fact that $f$ is continuous at $p$; everywhere continuity is redundant. Besides, if we are only given information for a given point $p$, it would be weird for it to affect continuity or discontinuity everywhere so, I think the statement needs to be modified to include $f$ is continuous at $p$. Also, **I am not sure how to prove the "if part"**.

Comment: There is a very importanti difference between $\forall x,(A(x)\leftrightarrow B)$ and $(\forall x, A(x))\leftrightarrow B$

Comment: This need to be true for **every** sequence, else just take the constant sequence $p_i=p$ then continuity cannot be deduced from a single $f(p)$ value.

Comment: @Gae.S. I am aware. The way I write it to be clear is $\forall x \exists A(x)\leftrightarrow B$ versus $\exists A(x)\leftrightarrow B\forall x$ basically, $(\forall x \exists A(x))\leftrightarrow B$ versus $(\exists A(x)\leftrightarrow B)\forall x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is incorrect (at the very least, it is extremely misleading) in the form it is currently phrased. Here are the correct statements:

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$ be a function, and fix a point $p\in\Bbb{R}^n$. Then, $f$ is continuous at $p$ if and only if for every sequence $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}p_i=p$ implies $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}f(p_i)=f(p)$.

This is the pointwise version. The "global" version (which follows immediately from the pointwise version) is

> Let $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to \Bbb{R}^m$ be a function. Then, $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}^n$ if and only if for every point $p\in\Bbb{R}^n$ and every sequence $\{p_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}p_i=p$ implies $\lim\limits_{i\to \infty}f(p_i)=f(p)$.

Comment: Ah, so existence of only one such sequence $\{p_i\}_{i\ge1}\rightarrow p$ wouldn't cut it. All the sequences converging to $p$ must satisfy the condition $\{f(p_i)\}_{i\ge1}\rightarrow f(p)$ for $f$ to be continuous at $p$.

Comment: @zaira yes exactly.

Comment: I have been stuck with the proof of the "if part". I am trying to prove it by contradiction: $\exists\varepsilon>0$ such that $\forall\delta>0~\exists y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|y-p\|<\delta$ but, $\|f(y)-f(p)\|>\varepsilon$. Not sure where to go from here. Any hint on that, please?

Comment: @zaira Ok, you know there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ blablabla. Since this is true for every $\delta>0$, it implies that for each $k\in\Bbb{N}$, we can find a $p_k\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\lVert y-p_k\rVert<\frac{1}{k}$ (i.e I'm applying the assumption to each $\delta_k=\frac{1}{k}$) but $\lVert f(y)-f(p_k)\rVert>\epsilon$. Now, justify why $\lim_{k\to \infty}p_k=p$ but $f(p_k)$ does not converge to $f(y)$. This will complete the proof.